# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor que yo quiera de un diccionario?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
print('Buscador de fechas de nacimiento')
print(' ')

nombres_guardados = {'Deysi': 'Deysi nació el 11 de abril de 1975', 
'Rafael': 'Rafael nació el 27 de octubre de 1975', 
'Miguel': 'Miguel nació el 16 de mayo de 1998', 
'Katherine': 'Katherine nació el 6 de julio de 2004', 
'Juan_Pablo': 'Juan Pablo nació el 27 de agosto de 2006', 
'Deborah': 'Deborah nació el 11 de noviembre de 2007', 
'Benjamin': 'Benjamin nació el 10 de octubre de 2010', 
'Maria': 'Maria nació el 25 de octubre de 2011', 
'Isaac': 'Isaac nació el 26 de septiembre de 2013', 
'Israel': 'Israel nació el 12 de septiembre de 2014', 
'Gilberto': 'Gilberto nació el 14 de diciembre de 2004'}

print('Un nombre por favor:')

nombre_dado = input()

for  nombres_guardados:
    print((nombre_dado))
```

Comment: Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¿Qué problema _específico_ has tenido? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: `nombres_guardados[nombre_dado]`

Comment: basta con reemplazar tus ultimas dos lineas con `print(nombres_guardados[nombre_dado])`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un diccionario cuya llave es el nombre de la persona y cuyo valor es un texto.

Si tienes una llave, puedes acceder al valor asociado simplemente con:

```
diccionario[llave]
```

En tu caso particular:

```
print('Un nombre por favor:')
nombre_dado = input()
print(nombres_guardados[nombre_dado])
```